# Data masking/scrambling

Tags: masking, data-masking

This is specifically for healthcare domain. What solutions/tools do you use to mask the PHI data while copying data from production to test environments

Comment: yes, kind of. the idea is mask/scramble the data so that PHI cannot be identified.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to the health care industry but we had a similar requirement for telco customers. We wanted to be able to provide representative data in test systems but ensure that no sensitive information was copied.

To that end, we tried a number of different things, including the ones we opted for:

1. Views that would be used instead of direct table accesses - these views would basically join non-sensitive information from the real table with dummy information from separate tables. The dummy information replaced all sensitive information from the real table.
2. Data transfers through a cleanup filter. This would basically unload the production database and pass it through an anonymiser program which replaced the sensitive information. For simple cases, things like addresses were all set identical.
3. Similar to (2) above but the filter could use data from specific lookup data. For example, an address could be formed with a 4-digit street number, a name selected from the 1000 most common street names, a street type (ST, RD, CRES, WAY, PLACE, etc) and a database of towns. A phone number could be any sequence of ten digits (subject to telco requirements) but with no duplication.